# year view for 2.6 version is needed

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to have year view for 2.6 version? We only see version 2.2.7 year view https://libraries.io/bower/fullcalendar-yearview/v2.2.7-yearview

Comment: Did you able to find solution?